# MongoDB: how to trigger time specific action based on time field in an entry in my DB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

**The Story:**

We have a MongoDB database that holds our users, who should take certain actions within 24 hours, after that they are not allowed to.

**Our solution:**

We created a background process that reads all the users accounts and check the 24 hrs time span. We do this *ONCE* everyday at night.

**The problem:**

We can't stop some users from taking actions because at the time of check, only 23 hrs (for example) elapsed, which mean those users will wait for the second day check to revoke their ability to do that action. This is not fair, because users are not equal, and our system is not consistent this way.

What is the best way to attack this problem?

Comment: Why aren't you checking the time range at the time they take the action?

Comment: @JohnnyHK. Because they may not take the action in the first place. Second, I want to take action on the non-acting users. They need to be marked after the time passage anyway

Answer (score 0):

I definitely agree with @JonnyHK in that you should just check the timestamp when the user is performing the action, so:

1. as soon as the 24 hour window starts for a user, set a timestamp on their object to the current time
2. when the user attempts to perform the action, check the current time minus that timestamp on their account to see if its been under 24 hours
3. if more than 24 hours has gone by, forbid the action

Alternatively you could just run your background process once every hour or once every 10 minutes even. Then if you miss anything, it will only be live for a small 10 minute window. You could just make a mongo query to only select users who's 24 hour period was just exceeded. You haven't provided a programming language, but something like `User.where({ :timestamp.lte => 24.hours.ago }).each{ |x| x.lock_user() }`. Then, assuming you've also indexed `timestamp` in mongo, this query will have minimal impact on your app.

Comment: Thanks Macmee ... 1- There is a timestamp already in the database. 2- The user may not do the action, so I need to behave accordingly. 3- That's what I'm doing, but every 12 hrs